# How do I get the RGB value for where my mouse clicks in pygame and how do I change the colour? (Python 3.3.2)

Tags: python, pygame, paint

So I'm using pygame to make a paint program. I've already loaded color spectrum for where I should make my mouse click. Except that, I'm not really sure on how to use the .get_at to find out the color and I'm not really sure how to change the color.

My code so far is:

```
color = []
color = ((0,0,0))
running = True
while running:
    mb = mouse.get_pressed()
    mx,my = mouse.get_pos()
    if mb[0] == 1 and palette.collidepoint(mx,my):
        color = screen.get_at((mx,my))
        color.append()
```

Every time I click on my color palette, my colo

Comment: you haven't finished your post, what happens with the color when you click on the color palette?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,480])
mousepressed = False
color = (0,0,0,255)
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mousepressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mousepressed = False
    if mousepressed:
        screen.set_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos(),color)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Sorry, in a rush, hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, was helpful to start.  Is there an easy way to display an image on that screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
mouseState = mouse.get_pressed()

mx, my = mouse.get_pos()
if mouseState[0]:
    color = screen.get_at((mx, my))
    # color is a Color object
    # Do some color manipulation by using Color.r, Color.g, Color.b, and Color.a
    # For example Color.r = 25
    # And at last...
    screen.set_at((mx, my), color)
```

Is that what you wanted? Read the docs to see what values Color.r and so on can be.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html